# How to round a number including least significant zeros?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to execute following SQL query in Oracle

```
Select round ( 123.50000065 , 4 ) from dual;
Output : 123.5
Required output: 123.5000
```

Any help is appreciated. ..

Comment: What would you have for 123.00005, 123.00004 , 123.00008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `to_char` with [required format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm):

Below rounds the value to 4 decimal places and formats into the required string:

```
Select to_char(123.50000065, '999999999990D9999') x from dual;
```

If you don't want to actually round the number i.e. you just want to truncate after 4 digits, use:

```
Select to_char(trunc(123.50000065, 4), '999999999990D9999') x from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )

```
SELECT ROUND(123.9994, 3), ROUND(123.9995, 3);
```

Output:

123.9990    124.0000

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `round()`, use `to_char()` or `cast()` to a decimal type:

```
select to_char(val, '999.9999'),
       cast(val as decimal(10, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

To control the format a number is showed, you can cast it to a string, by applying the right format mask.

Depending on how you need round your input value, one of these could be useful:

```
with test(x) as (
    select 123.50000065 from dual union all
    select 123.00004    from dual union all
    select 123.00005    from dual union all
    select 123.00008    from dual
)
select x, 
       to_char(x, 'FM99999999.0000'),
       to_char(trunc(x, 4), 'FM99999999.0000')
from test ;
```

result:

```
                         X TO_CHAR(X,'FM9 TO_CHAR(TRUNC(
-------------------------- -------------- --------------
           123,50000065000 123.5000       123.5000
           123,00004000000 123.0000       123.0000
           123,00005000000 123.0001       123.0000
           123,00008000000 123.0001       123.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

"Rounding" is a mathematical concept. The value (with your sample input) is 123.5. Mathematically 123.5000 is the same thing as 123.5. They are only different as STRINGS.

One way to display 123.5 as 123.5000 is to wrap `round()` within `to_char()`. However, this means you are not able to use it in further computations (actually Oracle will allow you to - it will do an implicit conversion back to number instead of throwing a data type mismatch error, as it *should* do).

The better way, in most cases, is to address formatting in your *client* software, like SQL Developer, SQL*Plus, or Toad. Here is how you can do it in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> Select round ( 123.50000065 , 4 ) as result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
     123.5

-- change the format of the numeric column "result"

SQL> column result format 999.0000

SQL> Select round ( 123.50000065 , 4 ) as result from dual;

   RESULT
---------
 123.5000
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you got `123.5` from your query. mine results `123.50000000`

if I understand correctly, you want your number 4 significant decimal places.
why not try `cast`

```
select cast(123.50000065 as numeric(38,4))
```

output: `123.5000`

testing if it rounds off number:

`select cast(123.50000065 as numeric(38,6))`

output: `123.500001`